# There is no Sharepoint 2013 Template in Visual studio 2013 Express edition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

i have installed VS2013 express edition for web. but in that sharepoint 2013 template not available in VS2013 express?

what i have to install for sharepoint 2013 template in vs2013?

am looking forward your answer.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio express version does not support SharePoint development. You should have Visual Studio Professional or above.

Answer (score 1):

The Office Developer Tools is built-in with the VS2013, which means you will get the tools after installing VS2013.

> the Office Developer Tools requires VS2013 Professional (or above) SKU. It doesn't work with VS2013 Express.

You can get the VS2013 at www.microsoft.com/.../downloads.